# How to manage a PowerPoint presentations programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone, powerpoint

Anyone know is any WINDOWS PHONE API is available  for MS PowerPoint Presentation Management.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_ but 2 upvotes?

Comment: Question isn't clear. Please explain what you're trying to do. Also, what's with shouting Windows Phone API?